# Where are the iAd fill rate settings in xcode ios6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, iad

Where are the iAd fill rate settings in xcode? I am running only on the simulator. I read on the apple website states:
"In iOS 6, you can further test iAd banner functionality in your developer-mode app by setting Fill Rate and Ad Refresh Rate in your device’s Developer Settings. Adjusting “Fill Rate” allows you to test cases when a banner is available and when it is not. By setting “Ad Refresh Rate,” you can more efficiently test how your app handles banner loading and errors."

I keep getting: "didFailToRecieveAdWithError" in my app that had previously been receiving iAds just fine.

I just noticed that in the Developer settings in iOS you can change the fill rate. Very good when I'm trying to implement google ads when iAds not showing and need to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This settings doesn't actually exist on the simulator. However, you can find it on a real device (that has been enabled for development) under:

> Settings->Developer->Fill Rate.

This being said I recommend testing on a real device. If you test on the simulator and something doesn't work, that doesn't really matter so long as it works on real devices.